# Manipulation of nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, I have `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` and I want `{{a,b,a+b},{c,d,c+d},{e,f,e+f}}`. I'm not finding a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 13):

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
{##, +##} & @@@ lst
```

> {{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}

```
{##, +##} & @@@ {{a, b}, {x, y, z}, {r, s, t, u}, {w}}
```

> {{a, b, a + b}, {x, y, z, x + y + z}, {r, s, t, u, r + s + t + u}, {w,
>      w}}

Comment: Very elegant... and generalizes to sublists of arbitrary length (+1).

Comment: Thank you @David. Good point re generalization.

Comment: Delicious! (plus filler to get to 15)
                        .

Comment: That ```+ww``` notation! I thought + was strictly an infix operator… I still learn.

Comment: @SHuisman, something similar works for `Times`:  `1 ## & @@@ {{a, b}, {x, y, z}, {w}}`

Comment: All the time @kglr has something very elegant to show. I will continue learning.

Answer (score 6):

```
Replace[list, {a_, b_} -> {a, b, a + b}, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

For example, you can map a function onto each element, like this:

```
Append[#, Total[#]] & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
(* {{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}} *)
```

Here, the pure function `Append[#, Total[#]] &` is applied to each sub-list in the list `{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`.

Answer (score 5):

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[1]] + #[[2]]} & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
```

> {{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}

Comment: Or this   `{#1, #2, #1 + #2} & @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`

Comment: Or `Flatten[{#, Total@#}] & /@ lst`

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0} and `Splice` (new in 13.1)

```
Comap[{Splice, Total}] /@ list
```

{{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}

Alternatively

```
Query[All, {Splice, Total}] @ list
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

```
Partition[Flatten[Riffle[lst, Plus @@@ lst]], 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[Append,{lst,Total[lst,{2}]}]

(* {{a,b,a+b},{c,d,c+d},{e,f,e+f}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Using `Reap`, `Sow` and `FoldList`:

```
Reap[FoldList[
Function[{acc, elem}, Sow[Append[elem, elem[[-1]] + elem[[1]]]]; 
Append[elem, elem[[-1]] + elem[[1]]]], {0, 0}, lst]][[2, 1]]

(*{{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

list.{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
```

> {{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}

And in a generalized form:

```
list = {{a, b}, {x, y, z}, {r, s, t, u}, {w}}; (* borrowed the @kglr's list *)

#.ArrayPad[IdentityMatrix[Length@#], {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, 1] & /@ list
```

> {{a, b, a + b}, {x, y, z, x + y + z}, {r, s, t, u, r + s + t + u}, {w,
> w}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

SequenceCases[list, {{x_, y_}} :> {x, y, x + y}]

Join[#, List /@ ArrayReduce[Total, #, 2], 2] &@list
```

---

*Result:*

{{a, b, a + b}, {c, d, c + d}, {e, f, e + f}}